# elephant-bird library generates default values of fields instead of null when an optional field is not set

Tags: java, apache-pig, thrift, elephantbird

I am currently using version 4.4 of elephant-bird-pig library. If I try to make a tuple from a thrift object, I expect that fields that were not set in the object, are marked null in tuple. However instead default values are put into the tuple. E.g.

```
struct PropValueUnion {
    1: optional i32 intValue,
    2: optional i64 longValue,
    3: optional string stringValue,
    4: optional double doubleValue,
    5: optional bool flag
}
```

the output of following should be (null,null,abc,null,null)

```
PropValueUnion value = new PropValueUnion();
a.setStringValue("abc");
System.out.println(ThriftToPig.newInstance(PropvalueUnion.class).getPigTuple(value));
```

Actual: (0,0,abc,0.0,0)

The problem is that isset information for fields is being lost during the conversion to tuple. Was it done deliberately and is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I expect that fields that were not set in the object, are marked null in tuple. However instead default values are put into the tuple. E

That's right. Whether or not an optional field is set can be detected by checking the `isset` flags.

```
public class PropValueUnion implements org.apache.thrift.TBase<PropValueUnion, PropValueUnion._Fields>, java.io.Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable<PropValueUnion> {

  // ... lots of other code omitted ...

  // isset id assignments
  private static final int __INTVALUE_ISSET_ID = 0;
  private static final int __LONGVALUE_ISSET_ID = 1;
  private static final int __DOUBLEVALUE_ISSET_ID = 2;
  private static final int __FLAG_ISSET_ID = 3;
  private byte __isset_bitfield = 0;

  // ... lots of other code omitted ...

  /** Returns true if field doubleValue is set (has been assigned a value) and false otherwise */
  public boolean isSetDoubleValue() {
    return EncodingUtils.testBit(__isset_bitfield, __DOUBLEVALUE_ISSET_ID);
  }

  public void setDoubleValueIsSet(boolean value) {
    __isset_bitfield = EncodingUtils.setBit(__isset_bitfield, __DOUBLEVALUE_ISSET_ID, value);
  }

  // ... even more code omitted ...

}
```

Comment: elephant-bird is a JAVA library. This question pertains to that library and how the library does conversion from pig tuple to thrift object and vice-versa, and not about the thrift semantics in general.

Comment: I already gave you the Java part. I now removed the C# part to make it less confusing for you. And your question is about the behaviour of `optional` fields in Thrift `struct`s.